# deleting files using command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

If I have a file lets say called 1.exe on scattered places in C:\ drive in many folders, is there anyway to delete all copies of 1.exe file from one command line, I've tried the command del followed by C:*\1.exe didn't work, any  help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

first change to your starting directory on your case c:

```
cd c:
```

then use

```
del /s 1.exe
```

source:
http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/184/recursively-delete-files-in-windows/